# Use the android Ktor client for call an api with search query

Tags: android, ktor-client

I want to use the android Ktor-client to run an API that has a query:

This is the Main Api: `https://www.filimo.com/api/en/v1/movie/movie/list/tagid/1000300/text/{Query}/sug/on`

How can I pass the `{Query}` to request with Ktor?

There is the BASE_URL config:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
    KtorModule.provideKtor.use {
            it.get {
                url(HttpRoutes.SEARCH_MOVIE_ENDPOINT.replace("{Query}", query))
            }
        }.body()
```

Answer (score 0):

like @Saeed Noshadi said, you can replace a known part of your URL with the actual query but it might get messy when you get more than one query to add.
hence I suggest to build the url with your BASE_URL and then add the remains part as needed in each API call
like so -

```
class ApiServiceImpl(val client: HttpClient) {
    suspend fun doHttpCall(baseUrl: String, queries:List<String>,) {
        client.get {
            url(baseUrl + queries.map { "/$it/" } + "sug/on")
        }
     }
}
```